# Hartl Chapter 5. Section 5.27

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm currently working through Hartl. In Chapter 5 i'm adding Hartl's code from listing 5.27 (below) to my spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

subject { page }

describe "Home page" do
before { visit root_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sample App') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
end

describe "Help page" do
before { visit help_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Help') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
end

describe "About page" do
before { visit about_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'About') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
end

describe "Contact page" do
before { visit contact_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Contact') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
end
end
```

Whe I run the $ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb test, Terminal returns this error:

```
Failures:

1) Static pages Home page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fb4b44504c8>
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Static pages Help page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fb4b46a9008>
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Static pages About page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x007fb4b4430290>
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Static pages Contact page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007fb4b40e57e8>
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21306 seconds
9 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33 # Static pages Contact page
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make `spec/support/utilities.rb` with the `full_title` method, as Hartl says?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this line in your spec_helper.rb file?

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Do you have a spec/support/utilities.rb file that looks like this?

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Do you have a app/helpers/application_helper.rb file that looks like this?

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

If so, I think your error should go away.

Comment: Out of the three, spec/support/utilities.rb was the only one I needed to change, however, the problem is still the same.

Comment: OK, sorted the problem my error. spec_helper.rb in not in support directory (placed it in spec directory). Thanks and apologies.

Comment: Ok, I have a few more ideas. Assuming you're using ruby 1.9.2, add the following to your Gemfile in (at least) the test group: gem 'ruby-debug19' This command will add a gem that allows you to insert breakpoints in your code. Then, open up the utilities.rb file and after the line 'include ApplicationHelper', insert the line 'debugger'. Then, run your tests from the command line. What will happen is, the tests will pause execution at the point of the debugger statement. When they pause, type in the command "self.class" and press enter. If it's wired correctly, you should see "Object" returned.

Comment: Let me know what that statement returns. If you're using a version of ruby other than 1.9.2, you'll need to use a gem other than ruby-debug19, pry is a gem I like a lot, provides more functionality, so I 'll modify the instructions for that. If you see something other than Object returned by self.class, it's probably that one of the require statements is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I also following Michael's tutorial for Rails 3.2 version and get the same error... try this with your current version of capybara

I changed the **:text** to **:content** and got it works, so it looks like this:

```
it { should have_selector('title', content: full_title('')) }
```

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The exercise in Chapter 5 reads

> "**eliminate the need for the full_title test helper** in Listing 5.26 by
>   writing tests for the original helper method, as shown in Listing
>   5.37. (You will have to create both the spec/helpers directory and the `application_helper_spec.rb` file.) Then include it into the test using
>   the code in Listing 5.38."

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout.html#sec-layout_exercises

Does that mean I only need "include ApplicationHelper" my `utilites.rb` file since `spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb` now contains

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
    it "should include the page title" do
      full_title("foo").should =~ /foo/
    end
```

Having this setup I am still getting an error when I run my RSpec test. They only way I can get it to pass is having `full_title` defined in `utilites.rb`

Answer (score 0):

The current formatting should look like this for your tests to pass:

```
it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }

it { should have_title(full_title('About')) }

it { should have_title(full_title('Contact')) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this post is two years old, I assume you have figured this out.  Nevertheless, try adding

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
config.include ApplicationHelper
...
end
```

within spec\requests\spec_helper.rb